# jQuery - Creating changeable sequential numbers

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a simple form using jquery. By building a form I mean I am putting together the inputs ready to post based on buttons clicked.

So for example I have might have a variable like so...

```
var1 = "<input type='text' value='some product' />";
```

Which when clicking the associated button will append the html to more of the same. A bit like a shopping cart.

The problem I have is this, I need to number them in order so when an input is added to the list it creates the relevant index number so it would end up

```
<input id="number1" type="text" />
<input id="number2" type="text" />
<input id="number3" type="text" />
<input id="number4" type="text" /> etc etc...
```

Thats simple enough, I just used var = count++
The problem comes when I want to have the ability to remove an item from the list. I am removing them for the list using
$(this).parents('tr').remove();

BUT when you remove one from the middle of the list the numbers are not then sequential. So my question is how do I keep these numbers sequential. is it how I add the numbers in the first place or is there a way of "revisiting" previous instances of the count variable?

I cant really give an example of what Ive tried here as Im at a complete loss with it. I have scoured the internet and Im not really sure what is possible or not.

Im not being lazy here just looking for someone to provide a solution but if you could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: i believe using jquery, the only way is to revisit and renumber the items. you could probably abstract this out with some code that fires up at DOM tree changes and does the revisit/renumber in background, but writing such a code would be just too much of time to provide this by me as an answer, maybe others have sth ready and will share :)  by the way, why do You need to renumber ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i found the problem so interesting, that i spent some time to create the answer.

I think a special jquery plugin could help You here, which i post below.
The usage example is on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FJRNh/

The way it works:

- isolate the "prefix" part - in Your case number
- finds all the siblings of the selected element which id start with the prefix
- removes the needed element
- renumbers the siblings

It has one drawback - it will renumber all items that have the same prefix, even if they were not numbered before, so if You have id's like number1, number2, number3, number_foot then also the number_foot would be renumbered. This could be avoided by adding a regular expression test in the inner loop. But i believe if You keep this limitation in mind, then the code provided will be just enough

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.renumberingRemove = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var mthisid = $this.attr('id');
        var name = $this[0].nodeName;
        var numberp = /\D+/.exec($this.attr('id'));              
        var sibl = $this.parent().children(name+"[id^='"+numberp+"']");
        $this.remove();
        var istart = 1;
        sibl.each(function () {      
            if (this.id != mthisid) {
                $(this).attr('id', numberp + istart++);
            }
        });        
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: of course the usage is simple: $('#number3').renumberingRemove();

Comment: just for completeness: it assumes, that the id's are constructed always with a pattern: prefix followed by a number, and the numbering will always start from 1